# How to store column values from mongoDB collection to another collection as headers using talend

Tags: mongodb, talend, unpivot

I have a mongoDB collection **HeaderDetail** with column names **headerName** & **metricType**. Below attached my collection detail,

[image]

Now, i was tried to store the **headerName** values as header in another collection using talend pivot component. But it is storing as a column values only.

**Expected:**
[image]

How to store the one collection column values as a headers in another collection?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in general: component's schema is configured before it started and can't be modified during runtime.

But you can do it using Dynamic schema (not available in free version of studio) and add columns using tJavaRow components.